# flatMap requires unnecessary casting

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
List<Person> p = groups.parallelStream()
    .filter(group -> group.size > 0)
    .flatMap(group -> {
        R r = callAsyncMethod(group.id);
        if (r != null) {
            return Stream.of(anotherAsyncCall(r))
        }
        return Stream.empty();
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`anotherAsyncCall` returns a list of `Person`'s. Right now, I get a compilation error, that requires me to change `List<Person>` to `List<Object>`.

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: try in this way `return anotherAsyncCall(r).stream()`

Comment: It worked! Why does it fix the issue?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh That fix works because `flatMap` takes a function mapping to a stream of stream of values, and converts output into a stream of values. Previously, you had a function returning a stream of List of values. By invoking `stream` on the list, you now have a stream of stream of values, which is the proper return type for the parameter provided to flatMap.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh `Stream.of(collection)` returns a `stream` with one element that is the collection itself. On the other hand `collection.stream()` returns a `stream` with the elements of `collection`. I hope now you got it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream can contain any type values, for example below stream contains list of string with list of integers

```
Stream.of(List.of("Deadpool","Iron Man"),List.of(1,2));
```

[Stream.of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html)

```
@SafeVarargs
static <T> Stream<T> of(T... values)
```

> Returns a sequential ordered stream whose elements are the specified values.

But [stream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) method just returns a sequential Stream with this collection as its source.

```
default Stream<E> stream()
```

> Returns a sequential Stream with this collection as its source.